# OSX connection configuration issue to rack application

Tags: macos

I am on mac ElCapitan 10.11.6 (15G31) and running simple rack application `rackup -p 5004`. I can connect to it with `http://localhost:5004/` and `http://[::1]:5004/`

But can't connect with `http://127.0.0.1:5004/` and `http://192.168.0.111:5004/`.

This looks like mis-configuration on my machine. I get different errors when try to connect with IPv4 and IPv6.

```
$ nc -v -4 192.168.0.111 5004 # and nc -v -4 127.0.0.1 5004 and nc -v -4 localhost 5004
nc: connectx to 192.168.0.111 port 5004 (tcp) failed: Connection refused

$ nc -v -6 192.168.0.111 5004 # and nc -v -6 127.0.0.1 5004
nc: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

But I can connect with `nc -v -6 localhost 5004`

My hosts file is pretty simple:

```
$ cat /etc/hosts                                                                                                                                                       
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

I need to make it work with my host machine IP address `192.168.0.111` so I can connect within Docker container. How to fix this?

---

Additional information I found on different topics

- scutil

  ```
  $ scutil -r 192.168.0.111
  Reachable, Local Address, Directly Reachable Address

  $ scutil -r 127.0.0.1
  Reachable, Local Address, Directly Reachable Address

  $ scutil -r localhost
  Reachable

  $ scutil -r ::1
  Reachable, Local Address, Directly Reachable Address

  # but note, ???
  $ scutil -r qwerty
  Reachable
  ```
- lsof port usage

`lsof` shows port is by ruby executable and the interesting part is `localhost:avt-profile-1`. Checking what `avt-profile-1` is gives results for "Real-time Transport Protocol media data". More info [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers). Also interesting is when I stop the `rackup` application there is no port usage, so this is not service/daemon running on my machine.

```
lsof -i :5004
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ruby    12167 kode   16u  IPv6 0xf3c39e30b59c5321      0t0  TCP localhost:avt-profile-1 (LISTEN)
```

Here I have different application running on port 5000. It's reachable via the host IP at `192.168.0.111:5000`. Note the NAME `*:commplex-main`. Addittionaly I would like to know what this is used for.

```
lsof -i :5000
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ruby    12889 kode   14u  IPv4 0xf3c39e30b22fcbe9      0t0  TCP *:commplex-main (LISTEN)
```

- host address name

  ```
  host 192.168.0.111
  111.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa has no PTR record
  ```
- arp

  ```
  $ arp 192.168.0.111
  ? (192.168.0.111) at a0:99:9b:17:16:1d on en0 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
  ```
- nslookup

  ```
  $ nslookup localhost
  Server:     192.168.0.1
  Address:    192.168.0.1#53

  Name:   localhost
  Address: 127.0.0.1

  $ nslookup 127.0.0.1
  Server:     192.168.0.1
  Address:    192.168.0.1#53

  1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa  name = localhost.

  $ nslookup 192.168.0.111
  Server:     192.168.0.1
  Address:    192.168.0.1#53

  ** server can't find 111.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.: NXDOMAIN
  ```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was `rackup` runs on localhost by default. To use host one must specify it with `-o` like `rackup -o 192.168.0.111 -p 5004`. Only one host can be specified.

Answer (score -3):

Ah, I had that same issue a while back. It turned out to be a bad script Chrome was executing. I solved the problem by using Safari instead.

Comment: This seems to be not my case. It's the same in Safari and  Opera. @chromaticsyllabus did you isolate which script was running?

Comment: For some reason nsIQTScriptablePlugin.xpt (ordinarily a Safari plugin you should keep running, see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203353) was being hijacked by Chrome. If you check Chrome's task manager you may be able to see this. Not sure if Opera has something similar.

Comment: I have the plugin too `$ locate nsIQTScriptablePlugin.xpt/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/Disabled Plug-Ins/nsIQTScriptablePlugin.xpt`


`$ file /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/Disabled\ Plug-Ins/nsIQTScriptablePlugin.xpt
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/Disabled Plug-Ins/nsIQTScriptablePlugin.xpt: XPConnect Typelib version 1.1`

Comment: I don't see this plugin in `chrome://plugins/` running `about:plugins` in Chrome address bar. Had 4 other plugins. Disabling them doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions